# Cutom account for Application Pool Identity

Tags: iis-7

I'm trying to set a Custom Account for Application pool identity in IIS7. In the Set Credentials dialouge box it's asking for

User name, password and confirm password. What would be the values for these fields?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a NT system account you have to enter user name as DomainName\UserName
and your Password.

Answer (score 1):

If your server is part of domain, you could use domain account for your apppool to run under and make sure that access has been setup for that account on that server (directories that are utilized by the application).  if that machine is not part of the domain, you could just use Local machine account.

In general, you can make AppPool to run under built in account or custom account.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't get you. Actually all I wanted to do is to set the Identity of the Application Pool to a specific account. user name: test, password:test1. But when I'm entering these values it's saying The specified password is invalid.Type a new password.

Comment: This is actually a much more complicated situation; usually it does *not* mean a bad password, something else is going on.  (I realize that this is an old post, but it still problematic, even in 2015)....